# SQL Compound query if-else or Case Statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table with Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Address1, Address2, Mail_Address1, Mail_Address2, etc etc.

In some cases, Mail_Address1 = 'Same' or ''.... which basically means that I need to extract Address1 + Address2 otherwise ignore and take Mail_Address1 + Mail_Address2.

My pseudo SQL Query looks like:-

```
// The query that would give me all the records with the same address as Address1 for Mailing Address //
    SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Address1 + ', ' + Address2 as Address, .... 
    FROM Customers
    Where Customer_ID != 0 AND (Mail_Address1 ='Same' or Mail_Address1 ='')
```

AND

```
    SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Mail_Address1 + ', ' + Mail_Address2 as Address, .... 
    FROM Customers
    Where Customer_ID != 0 AND Mail_Address1 !='Same' AND Mail_Address1 !=''
```

How do I combine these two queries so that I can have one query which would choose the correct address depending on the condition. (Same or empty string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a `CASE` statement?

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN Customer_ID != 0 AND (Mail_Address1 ='Same' OR Mail_Address1 = '')
    THEN Address1 + ', ' + Address2
    ELSE Mail_Address1 + ', ' + Mail_Address2
END AS address
FROM Customers
```